# Updating unique non-primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, unique-key

In my DB, I have a column defined as a Unique index. I generated my EF model from the DB (I don't know how this uniqueness was translated to the model. How do I check this?).
When I try to update this field in a record using

```
entity.Users.ApplyCurrentValues(user);
```

I get the following error:

> An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could
>   not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of
>   the supplied object match the key values of the object to which
>   changes must be applied.

How can I update a unique (non-primary!) field?

Comment: Would be useful to see your user model.

Answer (score 0):

We'd have to see some more code to determine where you're obtaining `user` object from to get a clearer picture of what's going on.

I believe `ApplyCurrentValues` is used to update changes that have been made to an object that already exists in the `ObjectContext`; if you didn't initially obtain your `user` instance from your context, you'll get the error above (the error is telling you it's unable to find the object you're trying to update).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx): `Copies the scalar values from the supplied object into the object in the ObjectContext that has the same key.`

You may well be able to `Attach()` your `user` if it's a detached object, or you may be able to load your `user` from this context and then use `ApplyCurrentValues` with the retrieved object.